# CSSで無限に横スクロールできるメニューバーをつくりたい

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

CSSで無限に横スクロールできるメニューバーをつくりたいです。

自動でスクロールするものではなく、手動で動かすものを作りたいと考えています。

いろいろ調べたのですが、
このような自動でスクロールされるものではなく、手動の。つまり触らなければ全く動かない横スクロールメニューを構築したいです。
https://qiita.com/mk668a/items/e6e73c32b8a8f943c94b

宜しくお願いいたします

Answer (score 2):

### 前提

「CSS で作りたい」とのことですが、質問文のリンク先のような動作をする手動のスクロールメニューは、現在使用可能な CSS の機能のみでは実現出来ません。JavaScript を使用する必要があります。

今回の回答では、 HTML, CSS に、以下のコードを使用します。

```
<div class="infinity-slide">
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/04/28/22/03/dawn-3358468_1280.jpg" alt>
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/09/14/22/51/cobblestones-3678292_1280.jpg" alt>
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/29/22/45/wheat-3506758_1280.jpg" alt>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.slide {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  height: 350px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

---

### 実現方法

質問者さんの実現したいことを行なう方法として、以下の 2 つを考えました。

- `clone​Node` メソッドを用いて、スクロール位置が右端に達したとき、スライダーのアイテムを複製する。

  この方法の良い点は、右端に達したとき、(複製された) 左端の要素が**なめらかに表示**されることです。
  しかし、右端に達するたびに、**スライダー内の要素数が増えて**しまいます。右端に追加した要素を消してゆけば要素数は増えませんが、カスタムデータ属性などを使わなければ、要素の順番が乱れてしまいます。
- `scrollLeft` プロパティを用いて、スクロール位置が右端に達したとき、スクロール位置をスライダーの始端へ戻す。

  この方法の良い点は、 `clone​Node` メソッドを使用した方法と違い、**スライダー内の要素数が増えない**ことです。もし、スライダー内の要素を追加、削除してはならないのであれば、この方法が簡単だと思います。
  しかし、右端に達するたびに、スクロール位置が左端へ移動するため、 `cloneNode` メソッドを使用した方法のような、**なめらかな動作になりません**。

---

最終的には、この 2 つの方法を組み合わせ、以下のようなコードになりました。1 度だけ複製を作り、 2 回目以降は `scrollLeft` プロパティを使っています。このようにすることで、ある程度なめらかな動作になり、要素数も単純に複製していく場合よりも少なくなります。

また、質問文にある Qiita の記事と同じように、最初の複製を行なわず、 HTML に 2 組分スライダー内の要素を記述しておいても良いですが、 2 回同じことを書くのは煩わしいため、このような方法にしました。

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".slide").forEach(e => {
  let endOfSliderPosition = null;

  e.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    const slider = this;

    if (slider.scrollLeft !== (slider.scrollWidth - slider.clientWidth)) return;

    if (endOfSliderPosition === null) {
      endOfSliderPosition = slider.scrollLeft;
      slider.append(...slider.cloneNode(true).childNodes);
    }
    slider.scrollLeft = endOfSliderPosition;
  });
});
```

```css
.slide {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.slide>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="infinity-slide">
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/04/28/22/03/dawn-3358468_1280.jpg" alt>
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/09/14/22/51/cobblestones-3678292_1280.jpg" alt>
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/29/22/45/wheat-3506758_1280.jpg" alt>
  </div>
</div>
```